# Transfer a 200 GB MDF file

Tags: sql-server-2005, file-transfer

Any ideas-quickest way, how to transfer a 200GB mdf file from one server to another?

Comment: Does this belong on ServerFault?

Comment: Are they in the same network?

Comment: An external drive?

Comment: @Vincent: an external drive connected how? USB 2.0 is quite a bottlenect given today's HD speeds.

Comment: @Michael eSata would seem the obvious answer

Comment: little to over hasted question ? usb, network share, robocopy ?

Answer (score 2):

Massimo recently asked [a question](https://serverfault.com/questions/111813/what-is-the-best-way-to-transfer-a-single-large-file-over-a-high-speed-high-late) that is somewhat similiar, albeit he was talking about a high-latency network. You don't specify what kind of network it is (gigabit Ethernet LAN, some kind of WAN, etc), but the [answer I gave there](https://serverfault.com/questions/111813/what-is-the-best-way-to-transfer-a-single-large-file-over-a-high-speed-high-late/111817#111817) might give you some ideas, as well.

In particular, the [uftp](http://uftp-multicast.sourceforge.net) utility that I suggested gave Massimo some pretty decent-looking results on his high-latency WAN. I haven't gotten a chance to test it yet over a gigabit Ethernet LAN but from its description it sounds like it would do a pretty good job of filling up a pipe.

It uses multicast IP to do the copying, so if you only end up needing to copy the file to multiple locations this tool would be a "win" immediately since the file only needs to traverse the network once to be received by an arbitrary number of destinations.

Answer (score 1):

I would make moving it safely the first priority, and speed second.
Safest way is to backup and restore, that could be made faster using backup compression tools such as litespeed - would result in a smaller file to copy / restore.

Less-safe options will be dettach / attach etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use the Microsoft eseutil tool. It's not specifically for this purpose (it's a tool to move large exchange databases around) but can be used for other databases and logs.

From Microsft: "Depending on disk and network conditions, copy file mode may be able to copy a file up to 20 percent faster than a normal copy because the copy file mode in Eseutil copies files in larger blocks of data."

More info at Microsoft [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998673%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx).

Comment: "The Exchange Server Database Utilities (Eseutil.exe) /Y copy file mode is optimized to copy very large files efficiently. You can use the /Y switch to copy a database file or log file. However, the mode is not suitable as a general purpose copy utility. "

Comment: I read it that the utility can be used for database and log files, but not for other general purpose copies?

Answer (score 0):

Well my first thought would be netcat, if you are on a Gigabit Network this should work rather quickly. [Netcat Examples](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2006/11/06/netcat-a-couple-of-useful-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

[Richcopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx?pr=blog) seems a good alternative (from [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/2850/looking-for-a-faster-way-to-transfer-file-to-a-windows-network-share/2938#2938)) if you can guarantee your local network runs at a decent speed.

Answer (score 0):

Given that a mdf is mostly text (unless you're storing binary images etc in the tables, in which case you should take a good hard look at what you're doing), zipping up the file will give some pretty impressive results. In the past we've zipped a 80gb mdf down to 10gb - this makes it a lot easier to copy around.